The security tag
The security seems rather redundant - isn't almost all cryptography related to security?

Looks pretty useless to me

I don't think queuing edits(as a low rep user) just to remove this tag is a good idea.

@CodesInChaos OK.

@Inkbug: In general, when you are editing a post (question or answer), try to fix as much issues as possible at once. If someone has to look at your edit to approve it, make it count.

@PaŭloEbermann Ok. Thanks for the tip!

The problem of this tag is that it is used quite unspecific. In the wider sense, almost everything on this site relates to security, thus it is useless here.
In a less wide sense, one often speaks of a $n$-bit security of some primitive or protocol, meaning that an attacker needs at least $2^n$ steps of work to break it. It could be useful this way (and in the past, I left out these usages when removing the tag from other questions), but it would need a good tag wiki for this, as well as some discipline (or regular supervision) to make sure it is not used when not appropriate.
Could we find a better tag name for this second (maybe valid) usecase, so we can ban the general one?

Perhaps [security-level] or [work-factor]

I suggest concrete-security.  @CodesinChaos's suggestions are reasonable too.

@CodesInChaos: Did you find/use a replacement tag for the valid use cases, or did you (and others) just remove the existing ones? (Sorry, I didn't follow the progress too close.)

@PaŭloEbermann I don't remember running into any questions where it was useful, but perhaps I missed some.

This tag looks useless to me. I've started to detag a few of the questions which have this tag.
